# Including a Sencha Component inside an XTemplate

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm developing a Sencha Touch application in which I'm doing lots of `Ext.extend` and creating my own custom components and classes.  I'm relatively new to the Sencha Touch realm, and I'm having a bit of a problem trying to use one of my components inside an `Ext.XTemplate`.  Here's a concept of what I'm trying to do in some code:

```
MyObj = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    cls: 'myClass',
    layout: 'card',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    monitorOrientation: true,
    config: myConfigObject.localObjectType,
    loc: 'en_US',
    initComponent: function() {
        // some random init code here…
        // Including:

        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="Available === true"><div class="itemAvail"></tpl>',
            '<tpl if="Available !== true"><div class="itemNotAvail"></tpl>',
            '<div class="formText">',
            // INSERT MY VIDEO COMPONENT HERE…
            '</div>',
            '</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            { compiled : true }
        );
    },
    // Object definition continues, but I don't think it's germane to this discussion…
});

Ext.reg('videoList', MyApp.views.VideoList);
```

And now the semi-code for my Video Component that I need included above:

```
MyVideoComponent = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    programID: null,
    chapterID: null,
    video: null,
    videoPlayer: null,

    initComponent: function() {
        var progID = this.programID;
        var chapID = this.chapterID;

        // Set up the video object based on progID and chapID

        this.videoPlayer = new Ext.Video({
            id: "videoPlayer",
            url: video.URL,
            posterURL: video.posterURL,
            fullscreen: true,
            autoResume: true,
            // configure listeners for play/end/error
        });

        // Call superclass.initComponent()
    },

    // Create listener callbacks for onPlay, onEnded, onError…

});

Ext.reg('videoComponent', MyApp.components.VideoComponent);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better to add the player directly to items instead of using a XTemplate there (BTW, XTemplate are always compiled, no need to set that config option), if you want to have, lets say, a view with thumbnails, then you should extend DataView instead of Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sencha Person] Our template language currently is a bit restrictive.  Once you drop into HTML for an item renderer, you cannot get back to the component level.  You can achieve the desired result by extending panel as a custom component that iterates through a data list and creates and adds the items to the DOM.

We'd like to make our templating much more flexible so you can accomplish what you're looking to do more easily, but at least in Touch 1.0, it's not a basic task.

Comment: We never could get this working the precise way that we wanted to.  Instead we had to add an interstitial page with an image that says "Click to play" which then loads up the video and hands off to the device's native video player.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you presented is quite conceptual, I can only provide a general direction to possible solutions:

I would try to break down the content in the page into multiple components and organize them (including the video component) with the layout system provided by Sencha Touch.

When using Extjs/Sencha Touch, the "proper" way to think of views is not to write them in html, but to construct them with components in the library as much as possible.

Comment: How to break up content seemed like a daunting task until I was able to take a step back and look at the big picture of Sencha Touch. Your comment about splitting it up into multiple components made perfect sense, it's the most powerful feature of ST! Cheers..